Are there usb pendrives that don't need to use safe expelling mode to be ejected?
I have a very vague recollection of reading something in this respect but have been unable to find it again. I think I read that you could configure something in the very pendrive that did the trick. Is it totally B/S? I'd like to solve this tiny doubt. Thanks a lot!

You should configure the OS, not pen.

It hasn’t been required to eject storage devices for nearly 19 years. You just can’t be actively using them.

The USB stick itself has nothing to do with this.
The Operating System needs to be configured to flush every write action to disk immediately, so there is nothing "pending to be written" when you pull the stick out of the computer.
The "Safe eject" options that many Operating Systems offer do nothing more than making sure all pending writes are flushed to the stick.
Having the OS flush all writes as soon as possible is possible, but has drawbacks:
It significantly slows write throughput and (potentially) increases wear on the stick.
And it is still no guarantee against data-corruption: You can still corrupt the filesystem on the stick by pulling it out in the middle of a write action.
But anyway. It is not a property of the stick. It is a feature of the OS.
